# compile error in Ubuntu 10

Tags: ruby, ubuntu

Hey guys
I got a vps which run solusVM. I'm now trying to install ruby 1.9.2 in it.

I follow this [guide](http://basedotextend.com/2010/09/30/installing-rails-3-ruby-1-9-2-phusion-passenger-on-ubuntu-10-04-lts/):

after I run this command

```
apt-get update
apt-get -y install build-essential zlib1g zlib1g-dev libxml2 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev
```

I got this error below

```
root@makserver:/usr/local/src/ruby-1.9.2-p0# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libc6
Suggested packages:
  glibc-doc
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libc6
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 80 not upgraded.
Need to get 0B/4252kB of archives.
After this operation, 4096B disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: Bad file descriptor
(Reading database ... 21594 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace libc6 2.11.1-0ubuntu7.2 (using .../libc6_2.11.1-0ubuntu7.8_amd64.deb) ...
open2: fork failed: Cannot allocate memory at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/ConfModule.pm line 59
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.11.1-0ubuntu7.8_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 12
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.11.1-0ubuntu7.8_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Anybody can tell me how can I correct this. Thanks

Comment: It is incidental that you were installing Ruby; The issue is with your OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple things look like you might not have enough RAM or disk allocated:

```
fork failed: Cannot allocate memory
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.11.1-0ubuntu7.8_amd64.deb (--unpack):
```

I agree with @zengr, this probably belongs on superuser.com.

Answer (score 1):

That's a ubuntu issue, belongs to superuser.com

Try this:
1. apt-get -f install build-essential zlib1g zlib1g-dev libxml2 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev
2. apt-get upgrade build-essential zlib1g zlib1g-dev libxml2 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev
3. Then again: apt-get -f install build-essential zlib1g zlib1g-dev libxml2 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev

Forcing an install might fix the problem.

Comment: thanks for your quick answer, I try your method but the problem still there

Comment: Wrong, it belongs on [askubuntu](http://www.askubuntu.com/), but yes, it's offtopic.